# Triggering Server-Sent Events in PHP

Tags: php, server-sent-events

The following code sends an update to the browser every second:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

How could I have the server send updates to the browser when the contents of a file or database change?

Comment: The question you are referencing is about how to achieve this on the browser. I am asking about server sent events.

Comment: Yes you can. Google "server sent events"

Comment: You are right.  My mistake